# How to use foreach to get all the GET elements with specific names

Tags: php, loops, foreach, get

He stackoverflow,

Today I am busy with an function witch get's all the elements with specific name. Now I have one problem creating this function. The specific name's are dynamic, so there can be: "conf_1=data&conf_2=data" but also: "conf_1=data&conf_2=data&conf_3=data"

Some code to enlighten you,

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
  $a++;
  if (strpos($key, "conf_$a") === 0) {
    $conf[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

So lets say we have this URL,

naam=name&dom=domain&id=41&conf_1=data&conf_2=data&conf_3=data&this_1=data&this_2=opt1

Now I am trying to get all the conf elements with the foreach loop but I need the $a parameter to be the 1,2 en 3 numbers. And when I try to take all the this elements $a shut give 1 en 2.

How can I declare that or how can I do this with an different loop. The next step is of-course to put the elements into an array like this:

```
 $conf = Array
        (
            [1] => data
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
        )

 $this = Array
        (
            [1] => data
            [2] => data
        )
```

It is important that the numbering is not done automatically. The number in the array shut be the number in the name of the element. Basically conf_1=data has to become [1] => data

I understand that there are multiple ways to do this but I don' t know witch are the best and the fastest ways. The way I am doing it now is complete wrong:

```
for($a = 0; $a < 99; $a++){
    // Get all the data
    $conf = array();
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, "conf_$a") === 0) {
            $conf[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    $finalconf = array();
    //order all data
    $finalconf[$a] = $conf['conf_' . $a];               

    print_r ($conf);
    print_r ($finalconf);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$list = array();
foreach($_GET as $key => $data)
{
    (strpos($key,"conf_") === 0) AND $list[ltrim(strstr($key,"_"),"_")] = $data ;
}
var_dump($list);
```

Output

```
array
  1 => string 'data' (length=4)
  2 => string 'data' (length=4)
  3 => string 'data' (length=4)
```

Comment: It comes a little closer but It takes all the get elements and then when you use $data array_values($data); It gives the array it own made keys and I want to give the array the keys of the name. Like this: conf_1=data has to become [1] => data. And that is Of course stored in the $conf variable

Comment: @sirwilliam that is easy .. i would update the code in a moment

Comment: @sirwilliam is this what you want

Comment: Yes it looks like it I will find my why with this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are submitting with a form (rather than with javascript for example), you can make it easier by converting the "conf" input element into an array.

```
<input name="conf[]" ... >
<input name="conf[]" ... >
<input name="conf[]" ... >
```

Upon submission, these would be available as an array in the form;

```
$_GET['conf'] = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

This is only helpful if you are submitting an **html form**.

Comment: This looks like a good and easy solution I will test this and try to compare it with the answer of Baba, PS I am using ajax GET method of JQuery to send the form. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$conf = array();
function check( $key ) {
   if( preg_match( '/conf_([0-9]+)/i', $key, $matches ) ) {
        return $matches[ 1 ];
   } else {
        return false;
   }
}

foreach( $_GET as $key => $val ) {
   $index = check( $key ) ;
   if( $index !== false ) {
       $conf[ $index ] = $val;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hum yes looks like it but how do I filter on the name this way. You see there is not a numeric key. The keys look like conf_int=data and not like int=data

Comment: The array $conf will have data like 1=>data, 2=>data etc. Isn't that what you want to accomplish?

Comment: No because the order of the numbering is not logic in some cases like conf_1=data&conf_3=data&conf_2=data. I need the code to order it so it becomes an array with the logical order